# NoMethodError for Rails form with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6

I have created a simple form with nested resources that looks like this:

```
        <%= simple_form_for [@user, @spot] do |f| %>
          <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :location,
                        label: false,
                        input_html: { placeholder: "location" } %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "btn-submit btn-red btn-fill" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

In my routes, I have nested accordingly:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :spots
  end
```

Method in controller:

```
  def create
    @spot = Spot.new(spot_params)
    @spot.user = @user
    authorize @spot
    if @spot.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Before create action, user is set:

```
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
```

The user id is included in strong params:

```
  def spot_params
    params.require(:spot).permit(:spot_date, :time, :location, :number, :bird_id, :user_id)
  end
```

Still, I get NoMethodError with the following message:

```
undefined method `spots_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fba929a7028>:0x00007fba929a56d8>
Did you mean?  user_spot_path
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the error thrown, is it coming from the view or the controller?

Comment: The error is in the view

Comment: Which part in the view - the form ?

Comment: Yes, for the first line of the form

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086366/undefined-method-path-with-simple-form does this answer solve it? Is @user initialized?

Comment: I'm 99% sure the error is due to `@user` being nil. Perhaps you didn't set the instance variable in the `#new` method? We need a more complete example of the controller and an excerpt from the logs which show the request that lead to the error to actually do any kind of debugging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes this solves the problem! I thought @user would be set since I had set ```before_action :set_user, only: %i[create edit destroy]``` but this was obviously only for create/edit/destroy. After I removed this part and call set_user before all actions it works. Thanks a million!